# How can I call a global function inside a method / property variable with the same name?

Tags: swift, function, methods, call, naming

For example, I have a property called `ceil` inside my class. Inside the function, I want to call the global function `ceil`. How can I do that?

```
class Example : BaseClass {
    var ceil : Double { return ceil(self); } // Error: Cannot call value of non-function type 'Double';
    func round : Double { return round(self); } // Infinite recursive
    var flooring : Double { return floor(self); } // Success
}
```

But if for example I don't want to use `ceiling`. I want to use `ceil`. How can I do that in this case? Is it possible? I'm thinking if I can call the global function such as `Math.ceil(self)` if it's possible.

Comment: The class inherits the `Double`, which seems to be illegitimate! You should get "Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'Double'"

Comment: @AhmadF sorry, it was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `var ceil : Double { return Darwin.ceil(self) }`

You should use an extension for your use case, no need to create a new class. This way you can use the methods whenever you needed on a `Double` without instantiating a new class

```
extension Double {
  var ceil : Double { return Darwin.ceil(self) }
  var floor : Double { return Darwin.floor(self) } // Success
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I actually extends Double. The example is just a generalization. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `var ceil : Double { return Demo.ceil(self); }`

Here `Demo` is project Name.

Comment: Awesome! Never thought about using my own project name to call the global function. Thanks!